# com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@****.blob.core.windows.net/

Tags: apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am getting the following error message:

```
com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@*******.blob.core.windows.net/cook/processYear=2021/processMonth=01/processDay=09/processHour=00/part-00003-tid-4640843606947508963-f47b3f23-a580-40bd-ad0d-29229-1.c000.avro.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:264)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.initIOException(Utility.java:737)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:235)
... 23 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Blob hash mismatch (integrity check failed), Expected value is xmypzfnpTdq8eFLxZ49DhQ==, retrieved CY7+V9/JEfVroD5omBB2Uw==.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob$9.postProcessResponse(CloudBlob.java:1409)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobInputStream.dispatchRead(BlobInputStream.java:255)
... 53 more
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the code which you are running along with the complete stack trace of the error message which you are experiencing?

Comment: check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251557/comdatabrickssqliofilereadexception-error-while-re.html?childToView=263999#answer-263999 for full stack trace

Comment: is there any way to avoid this error or get around it where it can atleast read other part files and ignore this one?